# How to report all failures after entire test is complete?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, minitest

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 with MiniTest.  I know the best practice is to have one assertion per test, but there are cases wherein I want to dynamically make assertions, like when comparing arrays:

```
if added_skus.each { |s| assert(skus_in_cart.include?(s), "SKUs #{added_skus} or SKU amount do not match SKUs #{skus_in_cart} on Cart page.") }
  puts "Product SKUs #{added_skus} match SKUs #{skus_in_cart} on Cart page."
end
```

As you know, when it hits the first assertion failure the test ends.  I'd like to continue the test and report all failures after the test has finished.

I found a solution using an old version of test/unit and Ruby 1.8.7 (the add_failure method in the test/unit library), but I can't find a good solution for MiniTest and Ruby 1.9.3.  I would really appreciate some feedback (even if that means I'm doing it wrong - please point me in the right direction).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 - Combine assertions into a single assertion:**

You could write your current code as a single assertion by considering all the skus together:

```
#Determine the missing skus:
missing_skus = added_skus.find_all{ |s| not(skus_in_cart.include?(s)) }

#Assert that there are no missing skus:
assert( missing_skus.empty?, "SKUs #{missing_skus} do not match SKUs on Cart page." )
```

**Solution 2 - Custom method for asserting multiple elements:**

If you really want the assertion count to be per individual SKU (instead of the entire set), you could create a custom assertion method. Though I do not believe this adds any real benefit over Solution 1.

Example running code:

require 'test/unit'

```
module MiniTest::Assertions
    #Asserts that each element passes the test
    # Inputs:
    #   enumerable - The object to iterate over (ex an array)
    #   msg - Custom message to include in assertion failure
    #   test - A block that each element will be tested against
    def assert_each(enumerable, msg = nil, &test)
        msg ||= "No message given."

        failed_elements = Array.new
        enumerable.each do |e|
            self._assertions += 1
            failed_elements << e unless yield(e)
        end

        msg = " #{failed_elements} failed assertion. #{msg}"    
        raise( MiniTest::Assertion, msg ) unless failed_elements.empty?
    end
end

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test()
        added_skus = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
        skus_in_cart = ['c', 'b']

        assert_each(added_skus, "SKUs missing from cart."){ |s| skus_in_cart.include?(s) }
    end
end
```

Comment: That'll do it.  I thought about something like this shortly after posting my question, but after reading more and more about MiniTest I think the best thing is just to maintain one assertion per test.  I like Solution 1 myself.